# MVC owner - Customize 500 error with

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have created an MVC Framework. And I will wish to customize my error (error 500 in this example).

Currently on my site if there is a server error, Firefox shows me a completely blank page and Chrome displays me "Error 500".

I would like that when there's a 500 error on my site, it displays my custom 500 page.

So I add `ErrorDocument 500 ...` in my .htaccess.

Here is my .htaccess:

```
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8

# C'EST cette ligne que je viens d'ajouter :
ErrorDocument 500 http://example.com/500

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   # => pour que si in tape index, que hebergeur n'essaye pas d'aller vers index.php ou index.html
   Options -Multiviews

   # => activation de l'url rewitting
   RewriteEngine on

   # => verif que url saisi est ni un dossier, ni un fichier qui existe physiquement, ni un lien symbolique ...
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

   # => ... si url saisi n'existe pas physiquement, on peut faire ré-écriture
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>

# => désactiver le listing des dossier "index of" sans index.php
Options -Indexes
```

When I type in the URL `http://example.com/500` my 500 page is displayed well.

But when there is a true 500 server error, it does not show me this page ...
Firefox still shows me a completely blank page and Chrome still shows me "Error 500".

I feel that at my .htaccess, specifically this line:

```
ErrorDocument 500 http://example.com/500
```

is ignored.

Is there a solution?

Comment: Not the cause of your problem, but you should specify a root-relative URL to your error document, not an absolute URL. If you specify an absolute URL then the server will issue an external redirect.

Comment: What server / version of Apache are you using? The server should already be configured with an "internal" default 500 error document - you wouldn't normally get an empty response. How are you testing this? See also: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/85454/htaccess-errordocument-500-not-working/85777#85777